# Derivative of an equation involves diagonal matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives

$$f(X) = \rho(\mbox{diag}(X)\, e^T + e \, \mbox{diag}(X)^T - 2X - Y)$$ where $e$ is the vector of ones and $X,Y$ are $n\times n$ square matrices.

I am trying to calculate the derivative of the $f$ with respect to $X$, $\partial_X  f(X)$. However, having trouble to calculate the derivative of the $\mbox{diag}(X)$.
How can I find the derivative of the $\mbox{diag}(X)$? Does anyone know any good reference for me to check it?

(p.s = I know $\rho'$)

Comment: from where did this problem arise

Comment: @AderinsolaJoshua It arises from a matrix approximation problem and $\rho$ is the loss function that needs to be minimized, therefore gradient calculation is required.

Comment: What is `diag`?

Comment: $diag(X)$ is a unique function, the function describing the diagonal of the matrix $X$, how would you differenciate it/?

Answer (score 0):

$\def\o{e}\def\v{{\rm vec}}\def\S{{\rm Sym}}\def\d{{\rm diag}}\def\D{{\rm Diag}}\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$For
ease of typing, define the variables
$$\eqalign{
x &= \d(X) \\
A &= \left(x\o^T + \o x^T\right) -2X-Y \\
  &= 2\;\S\left(x\o^T\right) -2X-Y \\
C &= \tfrac 12(A+A^T-B-B^T) \\
  &= \S(A-B)\\
}$$
and use a colon as a product notation for the trace, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= {\rm Tr}(AB^T) = \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij} B_{ij} \\
A:B &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
Finally, in order to be concrete, I'll assume that the loss function is quadratic
$$\eqalign{f = \tfrac 12\big\|A-B\big\|^2_F = \tfrac 12(A-B):(A-B)}$$
Calculate the differential and gradient of the loss function.
$$\eqalign{
df &= (A-B):dA \\
   &= 2\;(A-B):\Big(\S(dx\,\o^T)-dX\Big) \\
   &= 2\;\S(A-B):(dx\,\o^T) -2\;(A-B):dX \\
   &= 2\;C\o:dx +2\;(B-A):dX \\
   &= 2\;C\o:\d(dX) + 2\;(B-A):dX \\
   &= 2\;\D(C\o):dX + 2\;(B-A):dX \\
   &= 2\,\Big(\D(C\o)+B-A\Big):dX \\
\p{f}{X}
   &= 2\,\Big(\D(C\o)+B-A\Big) \\
}$$
where the `Diag()` function turns its vector argument into a diagonal matrix.